# Why I have to declear class type in angle brackets when using Comparable or other interface sometimes？

Tags: java, interface

Such as:

```
public class Test implements Comparable<String>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(String o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm a java beginner and meeting some trouble.

Now I have a compareTo() method override from Comparable interface in Test class. I want to know if I can declare a parameter o with String type in this method why I have to declare `public class Test implements Comparable<String>` rather than `public class Test implements Comparable<>`. In other words, the compiler will give me an error unless I declare exact datatype in angle brackets after `Comparable`. So What does the datatype in angle brackets do and why I have to declare it first not when I really use it in `compareTo()` method?

Comment: You mean "Why do I have to write `<String>`?"

Comment: Please, can you clarify your question?

Comment: *"toString method's args"*? What do you mean? The only common `toString` method that I know is `toString()` — without arguments. You should definitely [read up on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: And declaring a Test class that implements Comparable<String> makes absolutely no sense. Making it implements Comparable<Test> would make sense.

Comment: Sorry, it is compareTo, it's clerical error

Comment: @user8954870 but what if you´d want to compare two integers then? you just declared it as `String`, so thats another overloaded method you have to write. Oh and whats with collections, double, float, BigDecimal and so on? They would all have to have their own method now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary purpose of the `Comparable` interface is to impose a total ordering on the objects of a certain class.

From this perspective it makes sense to specify the "certain class" as the type parameter of the `Comparable` interface itself.

Consequently you as a user of the interface are forced to provide the type parameter.